# socket-io: when a message is sent, how to display a message/notification to the root component / out of the chatroom?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets, websocket, socket.io

In my chat app when a message is emitted on a chatroom I want to display a message/toaster to the root component so that the person who is out of the chatroom will get notified.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('CC_Token');
    if (token) {
      const payload = JSON.parse(atob(token.split('.')[1]));
      setUserId(payload.id);
    }
    if (socket) {
      socket.on('newMessage', (message) => {
        const newMessages = [...messages, message];
        setMessages(newMessages);
      });
    }
    //eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [messages, socket]);
```

what I have tried is to dispatch an action and tried to update the redux store.
but the problem is reducer is not called.

What would be the best approach to achieve this

Comment: You can use [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) for that.

Comment: I did that. but reducer is not called.

Answer (score 0):

You use this code

```
const notifyMe = () => {
  if (!('Notification' in window)) {
    alert(
      'This browser does not support desktop notification please use Chrome, Brave, Firefox or update your browser'
    );
  } else if (
    Notification.permission === 'granted' ||
    Notification.permission === 'default'
  ) {
    var options = {
      body: 'This is body of notification',
      icon: 'notif.jpg',
      dir: 'ltr',
    };
    var notification = new Notification('Hi there', options);
  } else if (Notification.permission === 'denied') {
    Notification.requestPermission((permission) => {
      if (!('permission' in Notification)) {
        Notification.permission = permission;
      }
      if (permission === 'granted') {
        var options = {
          body: 'This is body of notification',
          icon: 'notif.jpg',
          dir: 'ltr',
        };
        var notification = new Notification('Hi there', options);
      }
    });
  }
};
```